# Loop all images from database and save them as a JPG file

Tags: c#, database, image, loops

I am trying to read all images from the database and save them as a jpg file, what i did was create a function that each image would recieve its ID as the name. my table looks like this with data present.

```
ImageCode  Image

DHS001     Long Binary Data
DHS002     Long Binary Data
DHS003     Long Binary Data
DHS004     Long Binary Data
DHS005     Long Binary Data
```

I did write a function that takes two arguments, image name and binary data could read the image then save it to a particular path but the problem is it well executes the read and write but the image remains the same, but the numbering of the image is ok

```
public void _setimage(string imgCode, byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    try
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn, 0, byteArrayIn.Length);
        ms.Write(byteArrayIn, 0, byteArrayIn.Length);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms, true); 

        finalImage.Save("D:\\" + imgCode + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        img = null;
        finalImage = null;
        ms.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

And the function that i used to loop the images from the database goes as below

```
public void createPhoto()
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) { con.Close(); }
    SqlcommandString = "select ImageCode  Image from ImageTable order by Barcode";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlcommandString, con);
    con.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Personaldetails");
    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    byte[] bimg; 
    while (dr.Read())
    {
         bimg = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1];

         // this here is where i call the save image function to execute 
         _setimage(dr.GetValue(0).ToString(), bimg);
    }

    dr.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through your table rows to get each image. For example:

```
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
   foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
   {
      _setimage(row[0], row[1]);
   }
}
```

You were only ever getting the very first row of the table.  If you iterate your DataSet there is no need to do the following while (dr.Read()). I also assumed you are using C# by what I saw above.

Comment: @Bels - If it works, can you please accept my answer?

Comment: @Bels - What I am saying is to accept the answer as solving the problem you mentioned.  There should be a button to accept my answer.